# Word for bias against or fear of foreign languages

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

This came up as I was writing a comment for a discussion on another site on the network*.  The discussion was about non-english creative works, and I warned against "xenophobia," but that's not quite right since the bias in question applies much more strongly to works in foreign languages than to works in English created in foreign English-speaking countries (e.g. England, Australia, Canada).  I'm looking for a word with connotations similar to "xenophobia" but that applies  to foreign languages (as specifically as possible) instead of foreign countries or cultures.

At this point I probably won't be using it in this particular discussion, but now I'm curious as to whether such a word exists. I've just thought of "anglocentric," but that's more England than English, and I'd prefer a somewhat stronger and more general term.

*: I'd prefer not to link to the particular comment chain; it's not a pretty discussion and I'd like to limit its exposure (besides, it's likely to get wiped by myself or another mod at some point). I think the meaning I'm looking for is quite clear without it.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is Xenoglossophobia

Comment: "Fear of strange tongues". Yup, that'll do.

Comment: @JohnLawler Agreed, but how about "xenolinguaphobia?" Does that work?

Comment: No. _Xeno_ and _phobia_ are Greek; _lingua_ is Latin. Technical terms match Greek with Greek and Latin with Latin. Since Greek falutes higher than Latin, it's more prestigious. Also less chance of unauthorized people understanding Greek.

Comment: A condition which shall join sigmatism as unnamable by those in its throes.

Comment: I believe *xenoglossophobia* refers specifically to the fear of **speaking** a foreign language.

Comment: Looks like the start of a good answer here. Can you add a reference? That is common practice on this site.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Not in any of the dictionaries I can find it in (though I can't find one I want to cite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term, as Tanninah mentioned, is Xenoglossophobia. I don't see why John Lawler said no. The term does not include *lingua*, it includes *glosso*, which is Greek for tongue.

So technically, Xenoglossophobia is the fear of foreign tongues.

Comment: +1, but I think you misunderstood John Lawler's "No."  I see it as being in response to John Landsberg's suggestion of "xenolinguaphobia.": ( @JohnLawler Agreed, but how about "xenolinguaphobia?" Does that work? –  John M. Landsberg Jun 23 '13 at 5:52)

Comment: "Automobile" is a common (not technical) English word that combines Greek "auto" (self) and Latin "mobile" (moving).  The demotic Greek word is autokinetikos.